# MyBatis XML mapper file in deployment WAR

Tags: java, mybatis

When using MyBatis and having XML mapper files, how does that information get included in the final deployment? I don't see my XML file in the contents of the WAR file, so I assume there is a compilation process that takes the mapper contents and somehow translates them into a class or some other output file.

Answer (score 0):

Store the MyBatis configuration files in the src/main/resources file in your Maven project.
These will be copied into the classes directory in the war file.

If you are not using maven,
step 1: use maven.